# Export MSSQL Server 2008 temp table into excel spreadsheet

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure created in MSSQL 2005 which stores the data in a global temp table (##Temp). When i use the export wizard function in MSSQL 2005 I am able to export the data into a excel file.

However when I run the same stored procedure in MSSQL 2008 and try to export the data in the temp table into a excel file using the export wizard, I am getting a Invalid object Name '##Temp' error.

May I know why is this so and How can I rectify it. Please advise on how to solve it.

This is the part of the Stored Procedure where i am creating a global temp table

```
 SET @SQLStrMain = RTRIM(@SQLStrMain_Prefix)
 SET @SQLStrMain = @SQLStrMain + ',' + RTRIM(@SQLStrMain_Txn)
 SET @SQLStrMain = @SQLStrMain + ',' +  RTRIM(@SQLStrMain_Amt)
 SET @SQLStrMain = @SQLStrMain + ' INTO ##Temp '
 SET @SQLStrMain = @SQLStrMain + ' FROM ( '
 SET @SQLStrMain = @SQLStrMain + RTRIM(@SQLStrSub) 
 SET @SQLStrMain = @SQLStrMain + RTRIM(@SQLStrMain_Postfix)
 EXEC (SQLStrMain )
```

According to MSDN, MSSQL 2008 does supports ##Temp naming conventions

Comment: Well, can't you rename your `##Temp` table to something simpler, like `TemporaryTable`?

Comment: Have you tried what Radu suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Radu Gheorghiu idea, I changed the ##Temp to TempTable(without the ##) and than i use the command

```
 Drop Table TempTable
```

To remove the TempTable after executing the SP. So thus, whenever I rerun the sp i will not have any issues.